# need to display 404 error with a meaning full message on the login view

Tags: angularjs

I have a login view, on submission of user credentials , a service will called with a post request ,here I am getting the 404, I need display a meaning full message for 404 error on the login view, which I am not able to,
could some one help me and suggest a workaround for this?

---

Below are the routes:

```
    $stateProvider
    .**state("/",{
        url:'/',       
templateUrl:'./resources/js/baseapp/ContactLogin/views/login.html',
        controller:'contactLoginCtrl'
    })**

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");


Below is the service

 var indata = { "password": pword, "username":uname };
             var req ={
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: 'http://localhost:8083/spring2/login',
                      data: indata
                      }

                  $http(req).then(function (response) {
                      console.log(response);

 // *here I am getting the 404, need to redirecr from serivce to view with error displayed on view*

                  }, function (error) {
                      console.log(error)

                  });
                }
            }
```

I saw few post regarding this on stack overflow they are displaying a complete page of 404 error, I don't need that, I need the same view on top it a meaning full message.

I have to redirect to templateUrl with an additional meaning full message, this message should be removed automatically if again a resubmisssion happens from the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a service/factory to make the login call, then you can get the response object at controller using promise .and there you can show the response object in view.

Comment: thank you, I could not understant , could u please provide me a code snippet

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

what i understood is, on failure of login you don't want to redirect.and you need to show just a message on view.right?

Comment: thanks for respondig, need to show the message on the view , redirected from the service

Comment: If you are writing your service call in factory/service, you can not show the response message directly from service.you should pass it to a controller which is associated with target view

Comment: Or you need to make the $http call from controller, then you can show the failure message to view directly

Comment: no need not make the $http call from controller, I am making the $http call from service.....could you please tell mne how to send the response to the associated controller from the service